# How Do I Make A Change A Volume With A Slider?

Tags: c#, slider, volume, unity-game-engine

Im currently working on a settings tab for my game and I was wondering **How Do You Effect Volume With A Slider?**. Now I know this is kind of a vague question, but I couldn't figure out how to break this question into a simpler part

Feedback is always appreciated **;)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create slider programmatically  and give volume control to the slider.

```
public float slidervalue=0.0f;
public AudioSource audiocccenter;
public AudioClip myaudiocc;


slidervalue = GUI.HorizontalSlider (new Rect (padding +370 * wdpi, 440* hdpi, 90 * wdpi, 44* hdpi), slidervalue,  0.0f, 1.0f);

audiocccenter = (AudioSource)gameObject.AddComponent ("AudioSource");

myaudiocc = (AudioClip)Resources.Load ("Clip name");
audiocccenter.clip = myaudiocc;

audiocccenter.Play();
AudioListener.volume = slidervalue;
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: You should avoid AddComponent with string, it got deprecated with Unity5 and will soon be removed.